# Need to modify the GeoJson file for Australia according to apple's app submission guidelines?

Tags: ios

I need to upload the geo.json file for Australia while I am submitting my app to app store. On the apple's iTunes Connect, it is mentioned that the geo.json file must have one polygon element and  inside multipolygon element there must be at least one polygon element whose start and end coordinates should be same. Below is the geo.json data for Australia, but it doesn't have any polygon element inside multipolygon element. What changes do I need to make in the below written code:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Australia"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[145.397978,-40.792549],[146.364121,-41.137695],[146.908584,-41.000546],[147.689259,-40.808258],[148.289068,-40.875438],[148.359865,-42.062445],[148.017301,-42.407024],[147.914052,-43.211522],[147.564564,-42.937689],[146.870343,-43.634597],[146.663327,-43.580854],[146.048378,-43.549745],[145.43193,-42.693776],[145.29509,-42.03361],[144.718071,-41.162552],[144.743755,-40.703975],[145.397978,-40.792549]]],[[[143.561811,-13.763656],[143.922099,-14.548311],[144.563714,-14.171176],[144.894908,-14.594458],[145.374724,-14.984976],[145.271991,-15.428205],[145.48526,-16.285672],[145.637033,-16.784918],[145.888904,-16.906926],[146.160309,-17.761655],[146.063674,-18.280073],[146.387478,-18.958274],[147.471082,-19.480723],[148.177602,-19.955939],[148.848414,-20.39121],[148.717465,-20.633469],[149.28942,-21.260511],[149.678337,-22.342512],[150.077382,-22.122784],[150.482939,-22.556142],[150.727265,-22.402405],[150.899554,-23.462237],[151.609175,-24.076256],[152.07354,-24.457887],[152.855197,-25.267501],[153.136162,-26.071173],[153.161949,-26.641319],[153.092909,-27.2603],[153.569469,-28.110067],[153.512108,-28.995077],[153.339095,-29.458202],[153.069241,-30.35024],[153.089602,-30.923642],[152.891578,-31.640446],[152.450002,-32.550003],[151.709117,-33.041342],[151.343972,-33.816023],[151.010555,-34.31036],[150.714139,-35.17346],[150.32822,-35.671879],[150.075212,-36.420206],[149.946124,-37.109052],[149.997284,-37.425261],[149.423882,-37.772681],[148.304622,-37.809061],[147.381733,-38.219217],[146.922123,-38.606532],[146.317922,-39.035757],[145.489652,-38.593768],[144.876976,-38.417448],[145.032212,-37.896188],[144.485682,-38.085324],[143.609974,-38.809465],[142.745427,-38.538268],[142.17833,-38.380034],[141.606582,-38.308514],[140.638579,-38.019333],[139.992158,-37.402936],[139.806588,-36.643603],[139.574148,-36.138362],[139.082808,-35.732754],[138.120748,-35.612296],[138.449462,-35.127261],[138.207564,-34.384723],[137.71917,-35.076825],[136.829406,-35.260535],[137.352371,-34.707339],[137.503886,-34.130268],[137.890116,-33.640479],[137.810328,-32.900007],[136.996837,-33.752771],[136.372069,-34.094766],[135.989043,-34.890118],[135.208213,-34.47867],[135.239218,-33.947953],[134.613417,-33.222778],[134.085904,-32.848072],[134.273903,-32.617234],[132.990777,-32.011224],[132.288081,-31.982647],[131.326331,-31.495803],[129.535794,-31.590423],[128.240938,-31.948489],[127.102867,-32.282267],[126.148714,-32.215966],[125.088623,-32.728751],[124.221648,-32.959487],[124.028947,-33.483847],[123.659667,-33.890179],[122.811036,-33.914467],[122.183064,-34.003402],[121.299191,-33.821036],[120.580268,-33.930177],[119.893695,-33.976065],[119.298899,-34.509366],[119.007341,-34.464149],[118.505718,-34.746819],[118.024972,-35.064733],[117.295507,-35.025459],[116.625109,-35.025097],[115.564347,-34.386428],[115.026809,-34.196517],[115.048616,-33.623425],[115.545123,-33.487258],[115.714674,-33.259572],[115.679379,-32.900369],[115.801645,-32.205062],[115.689611,-31.612437],[115.160909,-30.601594],[114.997043,-30.030725],[115.040038,-29.461095],[114.641974,-28.810231],[114.616498,-28.516399],[114.173579,-28.118077],[114.048884,-27.334765],[113.477498,-26.543134],[113.338953,-26.116545],[113.778358,-26.549025],[113.440962,-25.621278],[113.936901,-25.911235],[114.232852,-26.298446],[114.216161,-25.786281],[113.721255,-24.998939],[113.625344,-24.683971],[113.393523,-24.384764],[113.502044,-23.80635],[113.706993,-23.560215],[113.843418,-23.059987],[113.736552,-22.475475],[114.149756,-21.755881],[114.225307,-22.517488],[114.647762,-21.82952],[115.460167,-21.495173],[115.947373,-21.068688],[116.711615,-20.701682],[117.166316,-20.623599],[117.441545,-20.746899],[118.229559,-20.374208],[118.836085,-20.263311],[118.987807,-20.044203],[119.252494,-19.952942],[119.805225,-19.976506],[120.85622,-19.683708],[121.399856,-19.239756],[121.655138,-18.705318],[122.241665,-18.197649],[122.286624,-17.798603],[122.312772,-17.254967],[123.012574,-16.4052],[123.433789,-17.268558],[123.859345,-17.069035],[123.503242,-16.596506],[123.817073,-16.111316],[124.258287,-16.327944],[124.379726,-15.56706],[124.926153,-15.0751],[125.167275,-14.680396],[125.670087,-14.51007],[125.685796,-14.230656],[126.125149,-14.347341],[126.142823,-14.095987],[126.582589,-13.952791],[127.065867,-13.817968],[127.804633,-14.276906],[128.35969,-14.86917],[128.985543,-14.875991],[129.621473,-14.969784],[129.4096,-14.42067],[129.888641,-13.618703],[130.339466,-13.357376],[130.183506,-13.10752],[130.617795,-12.536392],[131.223495,-12.183649],[131.735091,-12.302453],[132.575298,-12.114041],[132.557212,-11.603012],[131.824698,-11.273782],[132.357224,-11.128519],[133.019561,-11.376411],[133.550846,-11.786515],[134.393068,-12.042365],[134.678632,-11.941183],[135.298491,-12.248606],[135.882693,-11.962267],[136.258381,-12.049342],[136.492475,-11.857209],[136.95162,-12.351959],[136.685125,-12.887223],[136.305407,-13.29123],[135.961758,-13.324509],[136.077617,-13.724278],[135.783836,-14.223989],[135.428664,-14.715432],[135.500184,-14.997741],[136.295175,-15.550265],[137.06536,-15.870762],[137.580471,-16.215082],[138.303217,-16.807604],[138.585164,-16.806622],[139.108543,-17.062679],[139.260575,-17.371601],[140.215245,-17.710805],[140.875463,-17.369069],[141.07111,-16.832047],[141.274095,-16.38887],[141.398222,-15.840532],[141.702183,-15.044921],[141.56338,-14.561333],[141.63552,-14.270395],[141.519869,-13.698078],[141.65092,-12.944688],[141.842691,-12.741548],[141.68699,-12.407614],[141.928629,-11.877466],[142.118488,-11.328042],[142.143706,-11.042737],[142.51526,-10.668186],[142.79731,-11.157355],[142.866763,-11.784707],[143.115947,-11.90563],[143.158632,-12.325656],[143.522124,-12.834358],[143.597158,-13.400422],[143.561811,-13.763656]]]]},"id":"AUS"}
]}
```

Comment: I just found out that the above json has two polygon elements inside one multipolygonal element. However, when I submit this file to app store, I get the following error:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Every polygon must represent a closed region—that is, the first and last coordinate values must always be identical"
In your case, you need to close the polygon with [145.397978,-40.792549]]]]